# How do I identify duplicate logs in Microsoft EventViewer using XPath 1.0?

Tags: xml, xpath, event-viewer

I have hundred of logs like the one which follows. I would like to avoid displaying duplicates by creating a custom filter in the EventViewer with XPath 1.0, using text contained in [EventData[Data]] as match pattern.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="EDI BizTalk" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">0</EventID>
    <Level>3</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-05-15T10:45:07.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>2369788</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>##</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>some text ..</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

This is what I add when creating a custom filter within the Event Viewer:

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Application">
    <Select Path="Application">
 *[EventData[Data = following-sibling::Data
   and not(Data = preceding-sibling::Data)]]
    </Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

I have not been able to do so, I always get syntax errors. Can someone please provide some examples?

Thanks,
Ivo

Comment: Well what XPath are you using?

Comment: I just edited the question. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use
    Suppress
right below
    Select
syntax remains same but what you give in suppress wont appear. Give a try!